# Print string when "item exists in a list" in Jinja2 template

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

I'm trying to populate nsswitch.conf with values that are determined from a list. The list is of string:

```
openldap_nsswitch:
  - group
  - hosts
  - passwd
  - shadow
```

If the string is in the list I want to output something in the template.

```
passwd:         compat {% if openldap_nsswitch contains passwd %}ldap{% endif %}
```

How can I write a string only if my list contains a specific element?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here you are:

```
passwd:         compat{{ ' ldap' if ('passwd' in openldap_nsswitch) else ‘’ }}
```

Answer (score 3):

Compat didn't work for me:

```
{% if is in('passwd', openldap_nsswitch) %} ldap {% endif %}
```

Also, I was doing this outside of ansible.